# Finding the digit root of a number

Tags: java, math

Study question is to find the digit root of a already provided number. The teacher provides us with the number 2638. In order to find the digit root you have to add each digit separately 2 + 6 + 3 + 8 = 19. Then you take the result 19 and add those two digits together 1 + 9 = 10. Do the same thing again 1 + 0 = 1. The digit root is 1.

My first step was to use the variable total to add up the number 2638 to find the total of 19. Then I tried to use the second while loop to separate the two digits by using the %

I have to try and solve the problem by using basic integer arithmetic (+, -, *, /). 
1.Is it necessary and or possible to solve the problem using nested while loops? 
2.Is my math correct? 
3. As I wrote it here it does not run in Eclipse. Am I using the while loops correctly?

```
import acm.program.*;


public class Ch4Q7 extends ConsoleProgram {
   public void run(){
      println("This program attempts to find the digit root of your number: ");

      int n = readInt("Please enter your number: "); 

      int total = 0;

      int root = total;


      while (n > 0 ){
        total = total + (n %10);
    n = (n / 10);

    }   

   while ( total > 0 ){
     root = total; 
     total = ((total % 10) + total / 10); 
    }


     println("your root should be " + root);
}
```

}

Comment: The algorithm is recursive in nature, so think about modelling it that way  in your program as well.

Comment: thanks. I don't know if i can combine both while loops and still make it work correctly.

Comment: Are you getting the answer correct?

Comment: You can move that while loop in a method, and make that method call recursive with new numbers.

Comment: is % a basic arithmetic?

Comment: Sorry, I should have put basic arithmetic and %. I was trying to say i have to solve the problem by calculation.

Comment: _while ( total > 0 )_ total will always be greater  than 0

Comment: @Bhavik Shah I've written out the math on paper and it seems correct to me. But it won't run in Eclipse. All I get in Eclipse is "please enter your number" and it won't do anything else.

Comment: @JessicaM. I ran your code on eclipse the 2nd while is an infinite loop

Comment: @Bhavik Shah Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In the second while loop it should be while ( total < 9 ). Is that because the root will be a single digit less than 9 and more than 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it does run, but just a bit too much :-)

```
total = ((total % 10) + total / 10);
```

can't converge to 0.  Also, your program as it is will only handle very specific cases.  As others pointed out, this can be solved recursively, but also with just a double loop.  A succession of loops like you tried won't work.

Try this (on input vars are the same as in your program, it's really a plugin replacement for your two loops):

```
    do {
        while (n > 0) {
            total = total + (n % 10);
            n = (n / 10);
        }
        n = total;
        total = 0;
    } while (n > 9);  // need at least 1 more loop
```

After this loop n will contain the root number.

Comment: @user93353 indeed, as stated at the end of the solution the root will be available in variable n.

Comment: @user93353 i did not get a chance to run the code so far. After i wrote my code it did not work properly in Eclipse and I was doing other homework assignments.

Comment: @JessicaM. My question was directed at jvu, not you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can sum only last digit until you get a one digit number:

```
public static int getRoot(int n) {
    int root=n;
    while ( (root=((root%10) + root/10))>9  );
    return root;
}
```

Or with recursion:

```
public static int recursionGetRoot(int n) {
    if(n<10)
        return n;
    return n%10 + recursionGetRoot(n/10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(getDigitRoot(1));
    System.out.println(getDigitRoot(11));
    System.out.println(getDigitRoot(1924));
    System.out.println(getDigitRoot(2638));
}

public static int getDigitRoot(int n)
{
    if (n < 10)
    {
        return n;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        sum += n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return getDigitRoot(sum);
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
7
1
```

I'm of two minds about recursion in this one. It more closely follows what you're doing when manually solving it and as such makes sense, however it's not too hard to implement iteratively and as usual that's more scalable. I think in most cases it won't matter since performance is unlikely to be critical and you're unlikely to deal with numbers large enough to cause a problem for recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Other people have suggested this problem could be solved though recursion but I was not sure what they were referring to. Our class has not covered recursion so far but thanks for the example.

Comment: This is a bad recursion example as it has a while loop that calculates the final answer before the first recursion call. I've added an example in my post.

Comment: If by that you mean it's not purely recursive, then yes, you're right. But it performs better than a purely recursive method so I'd disagree it's "bad", and you can't argue it's not a recursive method. The reason I did it this way is because it's really easy to read as it performs the calculation in exactly the way you'd do it with a pen and paper, which also makes it easier to debug if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop to check if your number is more than or equal to 10, i.e. it has more than one digit. Do your digit addition in an inner loop. Print the your intermediate results to check whether your math is correct, i.e. print the digits you extract and the sums. You can remove this later if you like. When your number is less than 10, you have your root.

Comment: I'll definitely do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you test it yourself? Here's a very simple way to write some test (e.g. comparisions between actual results and expected results) and the math is correct if all those tests pass.

First we need to extract the math in a separate method, because we need something that takes input and provides output:

```
public void run(){
  println("This program attempts to find the digit root of your number: ");

  int n = readInt("Please enter your number: "); 

  int root = calculateRoot(n);    

  println("your total should be " + root);
}

public static int calculateRoot(int n) {
  int total = 0;
  int root = total;
  while (n > 0 ){
    total = total + (n %10);
    n = (n / 10);
  }   

  while ( total > 0 ){
    root = total; 
    total = ((total % 10) + total / 10); 
  }

  return root;
}
```

And with that at hand, we can create a `main` method to execute some tests:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  if (0 == calculateRoot(0)) {
    System.out.println("0: OK");
  }

  if (1234 == calculateRoot(10)) {
    System.out.println("1234: OK");
  }

  // and so on
```

}

So just implement your algorithm and execute the class and verify by the output, that all tests are OK. This is VERY simplified and later you'll use special test tools but the general approach will be the same: define some test cases and code until all the implementation passes all tests.

Comment: Thanks our class has not learned how to create tests out for our problems so far. I tried to do the math on paper and it seems to work. I'm just not sure if i correctly translated the correct answer into Java.

Comment: Did you actually run your program? It hangs for any input. It goes into an infinite loop in `while ( total > 0 )` because total is never going to be `>0`

Comment: Meant to write 'because total is always going to be `>0`'

Comment: @JessicaM., that's why I kept it really simple. The only additional things you have to know is how to create a method. The rest is more or less conceptual

Comment: @user93353 - me? no. I just refactored the code from above. The idea was not to correct the code but show a way that helps to spot the problems (= testing)

Answer (score 0):

2.Is my math correct? `Yes`
3. As I wrote it here it does not run in Eclipse. Am I using the while loops correctly? `No`
1.Is it necessary and or possible to solve the problem using nested while loops?

Yes it is possible using nested loops as the answers given by fvu above

```
do {
    while (n > 0) {
        total = total + (n % 10);
        n = (n / 10);
    }
    n = total;
    total = 0;
} while (n > 9);
```

Is it necessary using nested loop. `No` you can use recursion

```
public static void run(){
      System.out.println("This program attempts to find the digit root of your number: ");

      //int n = 234567; 

      int total = 23456;

    //  int root = total;


          total=Test.calctotal(total);

      System.out.println("Root:"+total);
}
public static int calctotal(int n)
{
    int total=0;
    System.out.println(n);
    if(n>9)
    {
        while (n > 0 ){
            total = total + (n %10);
            n = (n / 10);
        }  
        total=Test.calctotal(total);
    }
            else
                total=n;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Did you actually run your program? It always returns 0 - because for any `n <= 9`, calctotal always returns 0. So the final recursive call will always return 0.  if `n <= 9`, you need to return `n`

Comment: @user93353 done man..I actually did slight changes while posting here.

Comment: @JessicaM. note the addition of else in calctotal()

Comment: Yes i do. Thanks I'll take some time and look more closely at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int root = 0;
  int t = 0;

  while (true)
  {
    root = root + (n %10);
    t = n/10;
    n = t;

    if(t == 0)
    {
        if(root < 10)
            break;

        n = root;
        root = 0;
    }
}
```

or even simpler

```
int root = 0;

while (n > 0)
{
    root = root + n%10;
    n = n/10;
}

if((root == 0) || (root%9 != 0))
    root = root%9;
else
    root = 9;
```